# PHP not connecting to database for email and password

Tags: php, html

I have looked at similar questions on here and have found none that help me with this issue.

I have a database which contains a **user** table for **name, email and password.**

My HTML is a very basic form:

```
   <form action = "" method = "post">
   <label>Email  :</label><input type = "text" name = "email" >
   <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" />
   <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/>
   </form>
```

My php is:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "student_user";
$password = "";
$db_name = "Student_db";

 // Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);
 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) {
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $email - mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_email = '$email' and u_password = '$password'");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $active = $row['active'];
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $email and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count == 1) {
        echo "Login Successful";
    }else {
        echo "Login Unsuccessful";
    }
 }
```

When I enter the correct generic email and password I have in the database, it still echos that the login is unsuccessful. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Are you saving passwords in plain text in the DB??

Comment: For now. I want to have the basic form connecting to it first and then I'll worry about security.

Comment: Have you left action part purposely or its a mistake?

Comment: If you do not think about security from day 0, your app will always be unsecure. If you want to test connection, just look for email, without the password part

Comment: maybe mysqli_real_escape_string is mutating your email and password so that they don't match the db

Comment: @Shauna check line: $email - mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']); check this line its; = insted of  -

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar thank you I have been researching for HOURS what it could be. Thank you!

Comment: ... and now you get to rewrite the entire thing from scratch using `password_hash()` and prepared statements with bound parameters ...

Comment: @CD001 YEP. I'm just teaching myself slowly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**$email -** replace with **$email =**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "student_user";
$password = "";
$db_name = "Student_db";

 // Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);
 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) {
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_email = '$email' and u_password = '$password'");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $active = $row['active'];
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $email and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count == 1) {
        echo "Login Successful";
    }else {
        echo "Login Unsuccessful";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

There is issue with your assignment operator in your php code.
You are using

```
$email - mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
```

Which is wrong you have to use

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
```

you are using "-" insted of "="